# Creative way to spread out a range of positions

Tags: algorithm

Let's say I want to put players in a game. I need to give each player a starting position. Is there a creative algorithmic way to spread out the players. NOTE: Players do not start at the same time so you have no idea how many players there will be. You only know the possible maximum number of players.

For example assume I've got a chessboard. I could just start them in order

```
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
| 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7| 8|
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
| 9|10|11|..|..|  |  |  |
..
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|..|..|..|..|..|62|63|64|
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

I'd like to start the players somewhat far away from each other.

```
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
| 1|  | 9|  |  |11|  | 3|
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|  |  |  | 5|  |  |  |  |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |  |  | 7|  |  |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|  |  |8 |  |  |  |  |  |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |  | 6|  |  |  |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
| 4|  |12|  |  |10|  | 2|
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

Ideas:

1. I can make a handwritten table of starting positions

   I'm not against this solution but I'd prefer a solution I can use with different size grids
2. Do some heavy algorithm that places each player one at a time on the grid then to place the next one each checks every point on the grid to find the one point furthest from all filled points

   That's way overkill. It's also slow.
3. Other (insert your creative solution here)

One example I used to place things on circle. I basically reversed the bits so assume max players is a power of 2. In this case, let's assume it's 16

```
 0  -> 0000 -> 0000 ->  0
 1  -> 0001 -> 1000 ->  8
 2  -> 0010 -> 0100 ->  4
 3  -> 0011 -> 1100 -> 12
 4  -> 0100 -> 0010 ->  2
 5  -> 0101 -> 1010 -> 10
 6  -> 0110 -> 0110 ->  6
 7  -> 0111 -> 1110 -> 14
 8  -> 1000 -> 0001 ->  1
 9  -> 1001 -> 1001 ->  9
10  -> 1010 -> 0101 ->  5
11  -> 1011 -> 1101 -> 13
12  -> 1100 -> 0011 ->  3
13  -> 1101 -> 1011 -> 11
14  -> 1110 -> 0111 ->  7
15  -> 1111 -> 1111 -> 15
```

So if you map that to a circle you'll get starting positions in this order.

```
             __0__
         _15/     \_8_
        /             \
       7               4
      /                 \
     |                   |
    11                   12
     |                   |
    /                     \
   |                       |
   3                       2
   |                       |
    \                     /
     |                   |
    13                   10
     |                   |
      \                 /
       5               6
        \_ _       _ _/
          9 \__ __/ 14
               1
```

The starting order of each player is spread out. If there are only 2 players they will be on opposite sides of the circle. If there are 3 they will be the 90 degrees from each other. If there are 8 they will each by 45 degrees from each other. Of course if I knew how many players there would be at the start I could spread them out every easily but like it says above I don't know how many players there are. I only know the max allowed.

So, I'm wondering is there a similarly creative and simple solution for a grid instead of a circle. I could do some complicated thing like

```
 if (playerNum == 0) 
 { 
   put 1st player in center 
 }
 else if (playerNum < 5) 
 { 
   put next 4 players in one of the corners
 }
 else if (playerNum < 9) 
 { 
   put next 4 players in mid point of edge 
 }
 else if (playerNum < 13) 
 { 
   put next 4 players in the center of the of the
   formed by the clockwise triangle of the center
   a corner and midpoint
 }
 else if (playerNum < 17) 
 { 
   put next 4 players in the center of the of the
   formed by the counter-clockwise triangle of the center
   a corner and midpoint
 }
 else if (...)
```

That's no better than just making a hard coded table since each case is custom. Any other creative solutions?

Comment: What's the approximate size of your board? And what's the approximate maximum number of players?

Comment: Current project the board is 9x5 but I'm wondering if there is a more generic solution that doesn't need that info.

Comment: In such a small board, you can just use a handwritten table, as you said. A generic solution should depend on the size of your board and number of players. After all, this question doesn't have a "correct" answer...

Answer (score 0):

Well, in functional language I would describe a rule : take a random position samples until you have **n** of them, where distance ex: **arithmetical distance** `sqrt(x^2+y^2)` to closest existing start point is 7.

```
Position[{x, y}, _?(#>7&)] // Flatten
```

Now that you have **n** of them, pick one.

---

You can do this in start of the world or when ever new position is required. As you wanted to start the players somewhat far away from each other you can increase the size of 7. This will more or less guarantee that positions are in no way predictable.